form values not updated on change angular 18
I have a form in angular :
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12">
                <div
                    class="input-group mb-4 gap-2 px-3">
                    <label for="name">Name</label>
                    <input
                        class="form-control form-control-lg"
                        pInputText
                        id="name"
                        [value]="workflow.name"/>
                    </div>

                    <div
                      class="input-group mb-4 gap-2 px-3">
                      <label for="description">Description</label>
                      <input
                        class="form-control form-control-lg"
                        pInputText
                        id="description"
                        [value]="workflow.description"/>
                    </div>

                    <div
                        class="input-group mb-4 gap-2 px-3">
                        <p-button
                            label="Update"
                            icon="pi pi-thumbs-up"
                            type="submit">
                        </p-button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
      </div>
 </form>

I do instantiate the form in the constructor and read the workflowId in the URL:
this.form = this.fb.group({});

this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe(() => {
  this.workflowId = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.queryParams['workflowId'];
  console.log('Get Router Params:', this.workflowId);
  if(this.workflowId != null)
    this.getWorkflowDetails(this.workflowId!);
});

The getWorkflowDetails method retrieve data from external web service and set the values of the form:
private getWorkflowDetails(workflowId: string) {
  this.http.workflowsHttpService.getWorkflow(workflowId)
    .subscribe({
      next: res => {
        this.workflow = res as WorkflowResponse;
        this.manageWorkflowTasks(this.workflow);
        this.form = this.fb.group({
          name: new FormControl(this.workflow.name),
          description: new FormControl(this.workflow.description)
        });
      },
      error: (err) => {
        let message = ErrorsHelper.setErrorMessage(err);
        console.error('Observable emitted an error: ' + err);
        this.messageService.add({ severity: 'error', summary: 'Error', detail: message});
        this.loading = false;
      },
      complete: () => {
        console.log("Done");
        this.loading = false;
      }
    });

}
In this method I set the values in the input fields that i retrieved from webservice. This part works fine.
When i validate form values sent are the values we passed and they are not updated values...
For example: if initial name is 'workflow' and i set it manually to 'updated workflow', the value that is sent is not the form value...

You have to specify formControlName for the values to be applied to the inputs. When working with reactive forms, you don't really need to bind value, as this is taken care of automatically by the directive formControlName:
<input
class="form-control form-control-lg"
pInputText
id="name"
name="name"
formControlName="name"/>


It works better once I use formControlName .... Sorry for my delay. I was on other tasks

From my experience I can only recommend to create the form once in the component and update it from there instead of creating a new instance in the service subscription. It often appeared to me, that forms hold an old reference internally.
Init:
this.form = this.fb.group({
  name: new FormControl(),
  description: new FormControl(),
});

Subsciption:
next: res => {
  this.workflow = res as WorkflowResponse;
  this.manageWorkflowTasks(this.workflow);
  this.form.controls.name.setValue(this.workflow.name);
  this.form.controls.description.setValue(this.workflow.description);
}

2 further recommandations:
Use a function parameter, the snapshot might be different
this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe(queryParams => {
  this.workflowId = queryParams['workflowId'];

getWorkflowDetails has a subscription and is called itself in a subscription, which makes it essentially a subscription in subscription anti pattern. Use something like switchMap to remove one subscription. PS.: Don't forget to unsubscribe.

thanks for you comment and sorry for my delay. I'll try implementing switchMap.
